# PHP Script for Recent YouTube video using API v3

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

A while ago I made a script that showed the most recent video on a channel by adding the username to an &id=username in the URL. Recently, YouTube has began pushing people onto their new v3 of the API, and I'm unsure how I can update my code to get it to still work. The old code can be found below as a reference:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
/*A very long java script to make the page responsive was removed from this snippet of code
 */
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' . $_GET["id"] . '/uploads?max-results=1';

$headers = get_headers($feedURL, 1);
if ($headers[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 200 OK'): 
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
$i=0;
foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
      $media = $entry->children('media', true);
      $watch = (string)$media->group->player->attributes()->url;
      $thumbnail = (string)$media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes()->url;
      $vid = (string)substr($thumbnail, 22, 11);
?>
<style>
.videothumb {
     width:100%; }
.videotitle {
     font-family: 'Raleway', Arial;
     color: #e10707;
     font-size: 20px;}
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e10707;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e10707;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e10707;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #e10707;
}
</style>
      <div class="videoitem">
        <!-- DEPRECATED <div class="videothumb"><a href="<?php echo $watch; ?>" class="watchvideo"><img src="<?php echo $thumbnail;?>" alt="<?php echo $media->group->title; ?>" /></a></div> -->
        <div class="videothumb"><a href="<?php echo $watch; ?>" class="watchvideo"><img src="<?php echo 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/' . $vid . '/maxresdefault.jpg';?>" alt="<?php echo $media->group->title; ?>" width="100%"/></a></div>
        <div class="videotitle">
            <h3><a href="<?php echo $watch; ?>" class="watchvideo"><?php echo $media->group->title; ?></a></h3>
        </div>
<?php if ($_GET["debug"] == "1"): ?>
        <code>Debug Information: <br />
        Watch link: <?php echo $watch; ?> <br />
        Video ID: <?php echo $vid; ?>
        </code>
<?php else: endif ?>
      </div>      
<?php $i++; if($i==3) { echo '<div class="clear small_v_margin"></div>'; $i=0; } } ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php else: ?>
<p style="font-size:60px;text-align:center;font-family:Arial">:(</p>
<?php
echo "An error happened. Please send an email to ____ and include which member page you are receiving this error on. Additionally please include the following ID: " . $_GET["id"] . " and " . $headers[0] ; endif
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a channel's uploaded videos like in the guide: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/migration-guide#videos

Usernames are deprecated, use channel id instead. But if you are still trying to find a channel that you only know the old username, you can use [forUsername parameter in channels.list call](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#forUsername).